# Raid Partition Setup

Tags: partitioning, raid5

I have 4 drives that I would like to install a RAID 5 on.

1) 80GB
2) 2TB
3) 2TB
4) 2TB

Can someone help me figure out what the partition setups should look like?
I am installing ubuntu server 12.04 LTS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Throw away the 80 gb drive and create a raid partition on each of the 2tb drives and build them into a raid5.